# KeyCloak POST user with federationLink

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to make a POST request to our KeyCloak.
I can create a user with no problem but once i provide the post request with the federationLink this isn't picked up. I tried it both with the ID and the string of the Federation Link. I noticed that the added Attributed aren't picked up aswell.

The body i post is:

```
"username": "xx@local",
"email": "xx@local",
"emailVerified": true,
"enabled": true,
"federationLink": "qa.exn-dir.xxx.com/cn=xxx,cn=xxxx,o=xxx",
"attributes":{
    "PHONE_NUMBER": [
        "xxxx"
    ],
    "CARD_NUMBER":[
        "xxx"
    ]
},
"credentials": [
    {
        "type": "password",
        "value": "12345"
    }
]
```

And i post this to /auth/admin/realms/REALM/users

When looking at the created user this is still in the default federation and not the one we provided in the body.

Any idea how i could solve this?

Comment: You should add the user in your LDAP system and not in Keycloak.

Comment: @sventorben Thanks for the reply. The users that we need to create in case are external users and they need to be added in keycloak using the API. Atleast that is what i'm told.. But they need to be added to a specific federationLink. This is my first time using KeyCloak so i'm still new to the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

User federation in keycloak provide functionality to import user data from your selected LDAP system, source from keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#core-concepts-and-terms)

> Keycloak can store and manage users. Often, companies already have LDAP or Active Directory services that store user and credential information. You can point Keycloak to validate credentials from those external stores and pull in identity information.

That means keycloak does not store the user credential, keycloak only point to those external stores to validate the user credentials.

Quoting from your comment replying to @sventorben

> Thanks for the reply. The users that we need to create in case are external users and they need to be added in keycloak using the API. Atleast that is what i'm told.. But they need to be added to a specific federationLink. This is my first time using KeyCloak so i'm still new to the whole thing

In case of your requirement to create external users:

1. You can create it and store the user data information and credential in keycloak, that means you need to send the appropriate user data and credentials along to the keycloak so that keycloak can use it.
2. Or if you prefer to load the users data and validate the credential from your LDAP system, then first you need to register the external users to your LDAP system just like @sventorben said, and then let keycloak automatically synchronize these new users (based on your synchronize settings of the user federation) or if you prefer manually, you can do it via keycloak admin console.